# How to make request to Amazon Web Service using .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

What im trying is to send simple JSON data to specific Amazon endpoint. Implementation of web service that i want to request is not available in predefined form (in SDK) like AWS.EC2, AWS.SQS or AWS.S3 are.

I could also make HTTP REST request but why bother with signing and auth if there is sdk publicly available.

So again, how do i request specific endpoint with AWS SDK for .NET?

Comment: Have you read documentation on that?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Its obscure, there is also Java sample that uses SdkClientHandler class that doesnt exists in .Net SDK.

Comment: reffer this blog, it will helps you. http://www.codemag.com/Article/1003071/Using-the-Amazon-Web-Service-SDK-for-.NET

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Thank You but it doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Which endpoint? There are a lot of AWS endpoints in the API reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

Comment: There is no documentation online for Yard Preregistration API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by writing REST HTTP class.

Its not what i wanted to do in the first place. AWS .Net SDK does not seem to help with making such request, nor with signing.